# PayPal Webpage Not Available in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have just stepped through the PayPal Express Checkout Digital Goods integration wizard at https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecdigitalgoods.

I am having what might be a Chrome-specific issue.

When one clicks the "Pay with PayPal" button, as expected, a new browser window opens and happily reports that it is "loading," but just when one might expect to see a page, Chrome reports that the "The webpage is not available."

The page Chrome was trying to load is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=....

Ultimately, this seems to be a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET problem.

Visiting the same page in Safari does not create the error, but rather allows for the payment as expected.

Has anyone had a similar issue in Chrome or other browsers? Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: I am having the same issue, firefox and zafari working just fine.

Comment: same issue here, just started today

Comment: Any updates on this? Just started for me a couple days ago as well.

Comment: I've noticed that if I open the redirect url in an incognito window in chrome it works. Possibly related to this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84313

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but clearing all my paypal cookies "resolved" the issue. I've got an open support ticket, if they provide any useful information I'll port back (I doubt it).

Answer (score 4):

I just stumbled across this post and wanted to provide some (albeit late) feedback. 
Most issues in the sandbox are caused by cookies (In most cases because of a mix of production and sandbox cookies and the resulting conflicting information)

if you open a private / incognito browsing session, the issue should disappear.

If this is not the case, please file a ticket with paypal.com/mts

Furthermore, https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/digitalgoods_ec shows how to integrate the PP SDK (the integration wizard is a bit dated)

Comment: Using a private browsing session worked for me, as did clearing all Paypal cookies, as did using another browser that I had not PayPaled before. Thanks!  I know situations like these are hard to account for on the server, but maybe ask the dev team if there's any better "error message" they could return?

Comment: working on it - their reasoning is that it wouldn't be an exact copy of the live environment code anymore - this needs to be challenged as there are many more use scenarios where the live code is just not fit for testing purposes - e.g. available timeframes in Recurring Payments

Comment: I cleared any paypal cookie from chrome and this fixed it. The issue occurred after I logged into the PayPal account that the company I work for owns. I was using my own personal account for testing. So others doing this will probably run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to open a private/incognito session then you can open up inspector => Application=> Browse to cookies section and delete all the cookies.